# App Engine JPA setParameter not working correctly

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, persistence, jpql

I am having some issues getting a parameterised JPA query to return the correct results in a Google App Engine app.

If I construct the query with string literals, I get the result I want:

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select from DevInfo as DevInfo where DevInfo.timestamp = " + someTimeStamp);
List<DevInfo> foundDevInfo = query.getResultList();
```

But if make the query using JPAs setParameter I don't get any results:

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select from DevInfo as DevInfo where DevInfo.timestamp = :timestamp");
query.setParameter("timestamp", someTimeStamp);
List<DevInfo> foundDevInfo = query.getResultList();
```

Is there something I have to do to enable this functionality, or perhaps something wrong with my query. After studying the docs for a while, I cannot figure out the issue.

I want to use the later method because I understand that using string literals makes my code vulnerable to injection attacks.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: do you have the same issue with `query.setParameter("timestamp", someTimeStamp, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);`?

Comment: illegal JPQL in use there ... "select alias FROM entity alias ..."

Comment: I should note that timestamp in this case is just a string, so I'm not sure that Temporal type is required.

Comment: @DataNucleus After changing the query to your suggested legal version: `select di from DevInfo di where di.timestamp = :timestamp` I still have the same results. It works for string literals, but not set parameter.